# Use HTTP session in Django Channels

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have the following problem. I have an django web application and I need to upload CSV files and then stream them using django-channels. I decided to save the path of the uploaded CSV file in the http session.

From django-channels documentation I understood that I can access http session object inside a websocket, but using the following code returns an object which does not have the file path added earlier.

```
@http_session
def ws_connect(message):
    print("Connected on data websocket")
    print(message.http_session.__dict__)
    Group("data").add(message.reply_channel)
```

Result of printing the http session is:

```
{'modified': False, 'accessed': False, '_SessionBase__session_key':                        '92zcls0hxqlk1352xwja6tvytjebjfw7', 'serializer': <class 'django.core.signing.JSONSerializer'>}
```

My question is, can I really access the HTTP session in websockets? Or should I consider another way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you assume the file path should be in `http_session.__dict__`? Django's session objects use properties and dictionary-style access to access session data. `message.http_session['<your_session_variable>']` should give you the data you need.

Comment: @knbk I tried to get the data using the method you provided and it does not work.